# How can I fix this Postgresql error when copying a CSV file on Mac?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running into an issue importing a CSV file from my desktop. When I run the following command with \copy as well as :

COPY parts
FROM 'Users/James/Desktop/parts.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

I returns the following error

ERROR:  could not open file "Users/James/Desktop/parts.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

When I run the \copy as such :

Users/James/Desktop/parts.csv: No such file or directory

I've verified that both terminal and postgres has full disk access, however it just can't seem to find the file, I've ever tried moving the file to another directory and attempting, but it just can't see it.

Comment: Have you tried dragging and dropping the file into the terminal, to ensure the path is correct?

Comment: Strongly suspect you want an absolute path beginning /Users/

Comment: Yeah, it was the path, forgot the /Users/ - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful if you copy the lines of code from somewhere else and paste it in your command line.
Quote symbols copied from GitHub gave me a lot of trouble on my Mac :
' versus ‘  makes a huge difference .
So this
COPY schema_name.table_name(header_col1,header_col2, ...., header_col_n)
FROM '/Users/user_name/Downloads/file.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;

has worked for me.